# D3 - Update Pattern and y axis

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/chart-update-1

Its a D3 chart in and Angular app.

Its a bar chart with two sets of bars, the bars have start and finish positions.

I have horizontal grid line.

I'm using the General Update Pattern to redraw the bars when the data updates (in the exmaple I'm changing the date when the btn is clicked)

My problem I dont think the y-domain/ axis is being updated correctly so the updated bars are incorrect.

The old yaxis isnt removed and a new axis is added on top.

How can I remove the old axis when the data is updated.

```
private drawUpdate(data){
    this.createAxis();
    this.x.domain(data.map((d: any) => {
            return d.phase
        }));

        this.x1.domain(data.map((d: any) => {
            return d.phase
        }));

        this.getExtent(data);

        this.y.domain(d3.extent(this.values));

    this.chart.append("g")
      .classed('y-axis', true)
      .call(this.y_axis)
      .selectAll('text')
      .attr('dy', '-3');

    this.chart.append("g")
      .call(this.x_axis)
      .classed('x-axis', true)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")

    const bar = this.chart.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)

      ///Enter
      bar.enter()
      .append("rect")
        .attr('class', (d, i) => {
          return i % 2 ? 'bar-1' : 'bar-2'
        })

        .classed('bar', true)

        .attr("x", (d, i) => {
          return i % 2 ? this.x(d.phase)+(Math.abs(this.x1.bandwidth()-this.x.bandwidth())/2) : this.x(d.phase)
        })

        .attr("width", (d, i) => {
          return i % 2 ? this.x1.bandwidth() : this.x.bandwidth()
        })
        .attr("y", (d, i) => {
          if(d.start < d.finish){
            return this.y(d.finish);
          }else{
            return this.y(d.start);
          }
        })
        .attr("height", (d, i) => {
          if(d.start < d.finish){
            return this.y(d.start) - this.y(d.finish);
          }else{
            return this.y(d.finish) - this.y(d.start);
          }
        });

      //Update
        bar.attr("x", (d, i) => {
          return i % 2 ? this.x(d.phase)+(Math.abs(this.x1.bandwidth()-this.x.bandwidth())/2) : this.x(d.phase)
        })

        .attr("width", (d, i) => {
          return i % 2 ? this.x1.bandwidth() : this.x.bandwidth()
        })
        .attr("y", (d, i) => {
          if(d.start < d.finish){
            return this.y(d.finish);
          }else{
            return this.y(d.start);
          }
        })
        .attr("height", (d, i) => {
          if(d.start < d.finish){
            return this.y(d.start) - this.y(d.finish);
          }else{
            return this.y(d.finish) - this.y(d.start);
          }
        });

        //Exit
        bar.exit()
                .remove();  

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `g` element for the y-axis **outside** the update function.

In the update

```
g_y_axis.call(yaxis);
```

Why do you have all that code duplication inside the update function?

Put it all in a function and call it with a selection to update the selection.

Comment: The code duplication I think your talking about is the update part of the general update pattern I think